# Drupal 7 Change Content Type of Existing Node

Tags: drupal-7

I'm just getting started with Drupal 7 (and Drupal in general) and I have a question that the internet can't seem to answer.  If one of my users creates a node using a specific content type, is there an easy way to go back and change content types for that node?  I know I can do this directly in the database but I'm going to use this Drupal install on a large site and the users who will need to change a node's content type won't have access to the database.  I know I can also simply recreate the node using a different content type (and then re-link everything) but this seems like more work than necessary.

There is an old drupal module called [nodetype](http://drupal.org/project/nodetype) that would add the functionality that I'm looking for, but this module has been marked as obsolete and abandoned.  This leads me to think that this functionality has been merged into the core or is available in a different module.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

For those looking, this module will do it: [drupal.org/project/node_convert](http://drupal.org/project/node_convert)

Comment: Is there something similar for D8?

Comment: Not that I was able to find. We've ended up writing some custom SQL to change the content type in the database but this was only for nodes with the same set of fields.  If your fields are different, you'll need some type of mapping system that the node_convert module had.

Answer (score 22):

As mentioned by Cloudkiller, [node_convert](http://drupal.org/project/node_convert) module will be able to do this job for you.

There are two ways to convert the node:

1. **Individual node conversion**: Check the "Convert" tab on the node view page to convert the current node.
   [image]
2. **Bulk node conversion**: Goto "*Home > Structure > Node Convert templates > Add template*" and create template & then conversion node in bulk.
   [image]

Hope this will help !